# How to get the Current Date Time Formatted in Flex

Tags: datetime, flex4, air

I'm trying to get the current date time in Flex/AIR?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To get the current date time, just create a new Date object with no values into the constructor, like this:

```
    var CurrentDateTime:Date = new Date();
```

Formatting it depends on how you want to format it; here is one option:

```
private function CurrentDateTimeString():String
{               
    var CurrentDateTime:Date = new Date();
    var CurrentDF:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
    CurrentDF.formatString = "MM/DD/YY LL:NN:SS A"
    var DateTimeString:String = CurrentDF.format(CurrentDateTime);
    return DateTimeString;
}
```

Comment: While I'm glad you found your solution; this does not actually answer your question; but rather the question of "how do I format the current date"

Comment: True, but back then I probably didn't even know what I was looking for! I'll see if I can modify the title.

Answer (score 6):

```
currentTime = new Date();
```

From : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=08_Dates_and_times_5.html

and

http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/Date.html

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find the below, your links helped:

Answer (score 3):

```
private function CurrentDateTimeString():String
{

   var CurrentDateTime:Date = new Date();


   var DateString:String = CurrentDateTime.getMonth().toString()+ "/"+CurrentDateTime.getDate().toString() +"/"+CurrentDateTime.getFullYear().toString();
   var TimeString:String = CurrentDateTime.getHours().toString()+ ":"+ doubleDigitFormat(CurrentDateTime.getMinutes());
   var DateTimeString:String = DateString + " " + TimeString;
   return DateTimeString;
  }

function doubleDigitFormat(num:uint):String 
{

   if(num < 10) {
    return ("0" + num);
   }
   return num.toString();

  }
```